# Extra Space on the right side of my WordPress theme after updating WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, styles

I recently updated WordPress to the latest version and it seemed to have affected my sites settings. In mobile view there is an extra space on the right side. The content is fine but the menu extends into this space. The site is [www.yuledochieacademy.com](http://www.yuledochieacademy.com/).

Comment: I have checked there is no as such space as you mentioned, can you provide more specific problem or with some exact screenshot ?

Comment: @laraib if you open the website on a mobile phone you will notice the content is centered, but if you scroll right there is a large amount of unwanted space there making it look awkward.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have some script not enclosed in `<script>` tag (starting with `"@context" : "http://schema.org"`)

as to remove the problem with the space on right side remove the:

```css
body.custom-background { background-repeat: repeat-y; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tag error ive fixed that. Im still getting the extra space after removing the line as you instructed.